# Where is the com.apple.Xcode.plist stored on a typical mac installation with latest xcode?

Tags: xcode

Can't find it. Spotlight doesn't find it either. Strange!

Answer (score 8):

For Xcode 5, it's:

`~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist`

There's also some other dev tool stuff under the `com.apple.dt.` prefix:

**Instruments preferences:**
  　`~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Instruments.plist`
**Xcode Developer Preview preferences:**
  　`~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode-DP.plist`
**recent file list, with a settable maximum pref:**
  　`~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.LSSharedFileList.plist`

Comment: What does the ~ mean anyways?

Comment: @openfrog: I'm only giving you this one because it's difficult to Google special characters like this.  It's a built-in alias for the current user's (your) home directory, and works in really any shell or directory input (e.g. Finder's Go To Folder…) on any *nix platform.

Comment: I checked it. This locations still exists and these contains next useful files:
1 com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
2 com.apple.dt.xcodebuild.plist
3 com.apple.dt.Instruments.plist
4 com.apple.dt.Xcode.Playground.plist

Answer (score 3):

Solution: Navigate directly to

```
/(userName_home)/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Xcode.plist
```

Comment: Not there for Xcode 5 _(albeit 4 years after you answered this; didn't downvote you)_.

Answer (score 0):

Spotlight doesn't search in ~Library unless you ask it to.  Navigate to ~/Libary, then search, then click seacrh (Library) rather than search (This mac).